# how to get rid of timestamp and change column into date format R

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate

I have a dataset with a date format that is below. I want to:

**1.** strip the time off the date column, so that it becomes `2/06/2020` or better yet `2Jun2020`

**2.** then I want to make my column `Date` into date format, so that I can subset off it

```
> print(df$Date)
   [1] "2/06/2020 0:00"  "12/06/2020 0:00" "12/06/2020 0:00" "29/06/2020 0:00" "3/06/2020 0:00"  "25/06/2020 0:00" "25/06/2020 0:00"
   [8] "25/06/2020 0:00" "26/06/2020 0:00" "18/06/2020 0:00" "3/06/2020 0:00"  "4/06/2020 0:00"  "10/06/2020 0:00" "10/06/2020 0:00"

> summary(df$Date)
   Length     Class      Mode 
    16749 character character
```

I tried this but it returned all `NA's`:

```
df$Date2 <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
d <- c("2/06/2020 0:00",  "12/06/2020 0:00", "12/06/2020 0:00", "29/06/2020 0:00")
as.Date(gsub('(.*)(\\s\\d:\\d{2})','\\1',d),format = '%d/%m/%Y')
[1] "2020-06-02" "2020-06-12" "2020-06-12" "2020-06-29"
```

If you want it in `02/06/2020` format:

```
format(as.Date(gsub('(.*)(\\s\\d:\\d{2})','\\1',d),format = '%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y')
[1] "02/06/2020" "12/06/2020" "12/06/2020" "29/06/2020"
```

Answer (score 1):

building on previous answer:

```
d = "2/06/2020 0:00"
x = format(as.Date(gsub('(\\s\\0(\\d):\\0(\\d){2})','\\1',d),format = '%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y')
gsub("^0+(\\d)", "\\1", x)

# [1] "2/06/2020"
```